# fixed-layout ePub displays one page no matter in landscape mode or Portrait mode

Tags: epub

Do you know if it's possible to make a fixed-layout ePub which displays one page everytime in iBooks regardless of whether it's in landscape mode or portrait mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a combination of `<meta property="rendition:layout">pre-paginated</meta>` and `<meta property="rendition:orientation">auto</meta>` should do the trick.

cf. http://epubsecrets.com/fixed-layout-in-epub-3-0-draft-metadata-property-definitions.php

Comment: Add `<meta property="rendition:spread">none</meta>` to the opf file.

Comment: To be clear: I downloaded La Page Blanche sample (http://code.google.com/p/epub-samples/wiki/SamplesListing#page-blanche), and added these 3 `<meta>` tags to the `content.opf` file. Works fine.